# How to include a class file in php when clicking a submit form button

Tags: php

I have 2 pages, the **add.php** page and the **main** page.

When the added button in the main page was clicked, the main page will successfully display the add.php page.

This is the code that I have tried for the main page:

```
    if(isset($_POST['add']))
    {
       include('add.php');
    }
```

and this is the code I've tried for my **edit.php**

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <title>EDIT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form  method='POST' action="o.php">


    <input type='text'  name='username' value='<?php

    $textarea1 = ""; 
$pos="";
    if(isset($_SESSION['use'])){
    $textarea1 = $_SESSION['use'];

    }
echo $textarea1;


    ?>'>

    <input type='hidden'  name='fakename' value='<?php

    $textarea1 = ""; 
    if(isset($_SESSION['use'])){
    $textarea1 = $_SESSION['use'];

    }
echo $textarea1;
    ?>'>
    <input type='password' name='passwordz' value='<?php

    $textarea1 = ""; 
    if(isset($_SESSION['pak'])){
    $textarea1 = $_SESSION['pak'];

    }
echo $textarea1;
    ?>' >
    <input type='submit' name='editit' value='edit'>


    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php

    if(!empty($_POST['editit']))
    {
    $truename=$_POST['fakename'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['passwordz'];
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("sad");

    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE  users SET  username =  '$username', password='$password' where username='$truename'");
echo'CONGRATULATIONS YOU HAVE SUCCESFULLY EDIT YOUR ACCOUNT';

}

?>
```

and the problem goes here, it **display the form** in the **add.php** page but it **does not do the actions it just refreshes the page** and does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you don't have fields or buttons named 'add' in your form :)

Comment: First time with PHP? Homework? :) Btw, http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
session_start();


if( isset($_POST['add']) || isset($_SESSION['USE_ADD']) )
{
    $_SESSION['USE_ADD'] = TRUE;
    include('add.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks thankyou very much you haved solved my 24 hour problem thank you thank you verry much

Comment: BTW can i ask 1 more question what is the use of isset($_SESSION['USE_ADD'] and where did you get it

Comment: Please if his answer helped you like it and upvot it

Comment: check this link for sessions http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php so that you get the basics on sessions

Comment: Please upvot it if helped you... read http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php